# Cannot change the background color of tooltip

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a tooltip in  my page. But I dint not give any css to the tooltip. By default it appears in grey color. I tried changing it, but no effect.

```
<a title="hello" data-toggle="tooltip" >Send</a>
```

[image]

Comment: *I tried changing it* What did you try? Show us your effort please.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap V 3.3.7
this is the code I tried
.tooltip > .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: #413a5f;
  color: white;
  font-size:11px;            
}

<a data-toggle="tooltip" title="hello">Send </a>

Comment: Don't add code in comments, instead [edit] your question to add detail, and please check your formatting.

Comment: Also, did you add that styling before or after the theme you have applied? The order of CSS is important.

Comment: I have added the css after the theme

Comment: Then it should work. You are not reading my comments I'm afraid, not showing much effort at all, so I'm out. Good luck finding an answer.

Comment: @DavidG Thank tou for your suggestions and sorry, I read your comments but could not reply soon. Sorry for the late reply

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

```css
.container {
  margin: 25px;
}

.tooltip.bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow::before {
  border-bottom-color: tomato;
}

.tooltip.bs-tooltip-bottom .tooltip-inner {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<div class="container">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Some tooltip text!" class="customized-tooltip">Hover over me</a>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This works in the code snippet as you can see. So there must be some problem with your code. in that case I can not give any solution without seeing your code.